# ZF+DC as the boundary of constructive mathematics

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, constructive-mathematics, hahn-banach-theorem

This is mainly a request for references.

I seem to recall hearing somewhere that ZF+DC is "the boundary of constructive mathematics" in the sense that theorems not provable from ZF+DC are nonconstructive.

Can someone point me to a reference for a claim like this? (I may have seen the claim in Schecter's book on the foundations of analysis, but a quick skim didn't turn it up.)

(If my recollection is correct, and you'd like to shed some light on *why* ZF+DC provides a good theory of constructive mathematics, that would be great too.)

Secondarily, what's the primary reference for the fact that the Hahn-Banach theorem isn't constructive in the above sense, i.e. isn't provable in ZF+DC?

Comment: "Constructive mathematics" is a technical term. The informal usage in the sense of your question is rather different from it.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thanks, you're right of course. Still, any references to the informal claim (or claims similar to it) from my question would be helpful to me.

Comment: For Hahn-Banach, you can prove that it implies the existence of nonmeasurable sets of reals, while there are models of ZF+DC where all sets of reals are measurable, see [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm138/fm13812.pdf).

Comment: Whether or not DC is "constructive" depends on which constructivist you talk to! See for instance the comparisons here https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/constructive+mathematics

Comment: ZF alone is not constructive, so do you mean some constructive variation of it?

Comment: @DanDoel Perhaps I should ditch the word "constructive." I didn't mean anything technical by it. I thought there was some point of view according to which anything beyond ZF+DC is "ineffable" ("nonconstructive", etc. call it what you like). I'm looking for a reference for that point of view.

Answer (score 3):

The easy case for proving HB does not follow from DC is to combine:

1. *Solovay, R. M.*, [**A model of set-theory in which every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1970696), Ann. Math. (2) 92, 1-56 (1970). [ZBL0207.00905](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0207.00905).
2. *Foreman, Matthew; Wehrung, Friedrich*, [**The Hahn-Banach theorem implies the existence of a non-Lebesgue measurable set**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/fm-138-1-13-19), Fundam. Math. 138, No. 1, 13-19 (1991). [ZBL0792.28005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0792.28005).

Since it's morning and I don't remember all the subtleties, you might also find an answer in the first theorem of the following paper, perhaps by combining it with further results, though:

3. *Pincus, David; Solovay, Robert M.*, [**Definability of measures and ultrafilters**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2272118), J. Symb. Log. 42, 179-190 (1977). [ZBL0384.03030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0384.03030).

Answer (score 1):

A closer look at Schechter turned up the following quote, which may well be what I had in mind:

"Dependent Choice, introduced in 6.28, is generally considered to be constructive. In fact, it is the strongest form of Choice that is accepted by most schools of constructivism" (14.76, p. 403).

Comment: In your question, the word 'constructive' is an informal term. But the term 'constructivism' in the mentioned Schechter's quote seems a technical term, which has a clear meaning. I am confused what the 'constructive mathematics' you have meant.

Comment: @HanulJeon I'm not sure I agree that "constructivism" in the Schechter quote is a technical term. In the course of the book, he recognizes that there are many ways of making "constructive" precise. I think "most schools" in the quote alludes to this.